# Second Site Pages Library does will not let me add App Parts

Tags: content-type, wiki-pages, sitepages

I created a second Pages Library in my site as I wanted to lock down permissions to some pages.  In the Advanced Settings for the document library, I allowed management of content types and selected that the document library should be a site asset library.

I then attempted to manage the content types.  However, when I went to add the Wiki Page content type, I is not in the list of available content types.  The type is in use in the site as I can see it in my site settings.

The challenge is that when I attempt to edit a page in the new Pages document library I created, I cannot add a web part or a web app as those button are disabled.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Any particular reason why you decided to make the library a site asset library?  Asset libraries are designed to manage media content like image/audio/video.  If you want to put Wiki Pages into a library wouldnt it be easier to work with a wiki page library?

Comment: So changes to a wiki page library then it would let me add web apps to the page.  The annoying part was that it then showed the "recently update" column on the far left of all my pages in that library.  Will add a complete solution below.  Thanks Max

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So Max was correct I needed to add a Wiki Page Library.  After that I created the pages I wanted as normal.  (They were saved in the Site Pages folder.)  I then simply mapped a network location to my SharePoint site and moved the desired aspx file(s) from the Site Pages folder to my new Wiki Pages folder.

There was one outstanding challenge.  All the pages in my new Wiki Pages folder had a side navigation containing 'Recently Updated' information.  I changes the layout of my pages so they had a footer zone and embedded the code below in the footer zone.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
       var hideWP = document.getElementById("sideNavBox");
       hideWP.style.display = "none";
    });
</script>
```

Hope this helps someone else.